# Footnote out of the page leads to a huge overfull \vbox

Tags: footnotes, geometry, line-numbering

Consider the following example (it may require TeX Live 2021):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minimalist}
\geometry{
    papersize={7in,10in},
    total={40em,60em},
    footnotesep=4em plus 2pt minus 2pt,
}

\linenumbers
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]\footnote{Text}
\[
    L(1,\chi_k) = 
    \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{2\pi h(k)}{w_k\sqrt{-k}} & k<0\\[.5cm]
        \dfrac{2 h(k) \log(\varepsilon_k)}{\sqrt{k}} & k>0,
    \end{cases}
\]
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

The footnote is out of the page area (to illustrate the problem I increased the `footnotesep`):

[image]

I'm not sure what causes this problem. For example, removing `\linenumbers` seems to solve this problem, but why? Isn't `\linenumbers` just a conditional switch to decide whether to print the line numbers? Also I think the equation here may have something to do with the problem, since replacing it with pure text also solve the problem.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance~

Comment: your patches to the math environments looks wrong. Try `\AddToHook{env/equation/before}{\linenomath}\AddToHook{env/equation/after}{\endlinenomath}`  instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your suggestion. However I have one questions with your approach: it seems only `\AddToHook{env/equation/before}{\begin{linenomath}}\AddToHook{env/equation/after}{\end{linenomath}}` works, not with `\linenomath` and `\endlinenomath`. Is there any difference?

Comment: The first introduce also a group, so it could make a difference.